# Apache mod_rewrite not persisting the name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I usually put my mod_rewrite conditions in an .htaccess file, but this is a case where it must go into the httpd.conf file.
I am confused because what I want to do seems simple:
The root of the site is a nested directory: mydomain.com/foo/bar/
It just has to be that way.
I want to write a rule so a person can enter:
mydomain.com/simple and it will show content from mydomain/foo/bar
Also, if a person clicks around the site, I want the mydomain.com/simple/some-other-page structure to persist.
The closest I've gotten is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^simple$ /foo/bar/$1 [PT]
</IfModule>
```

However, using this rule, when a person types mydomain.com/simple it rewrites the URI in the browser to mydomain.com/foo/bar
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there may be a problem with this rule:

```
RewriteRule   ^simple$ /foo/bar/$1 [PT]
```

The expression `^simple` will probably never match, since all requests will start with a `/`.

You're using `$1` in the right-hand side of the rule, but there are no match groups in the left-hand side that will populate this.  This means that a request for `/simple` would get you `/foo/bar/`, but a request for `/simple/somethingelse` wouldn't match the rule.  If this isn't the behavior you want, you probably mean this:

```
    RewriteRule   ^/simple(.*)$ /foo/bar$1 [PT]
```

(Note that I've added the missing leading `/` here as well).

With these changes in place, this rule behaves on my system as I think you're expecting.

Lastly, turning on the `RewriteLog` and setting `RewriteLogLevel` (assuming a pre-2.4 version of Apache) will help expose the details of exactly what's happening.